How to load secrets from file on build in unity c#?
I have a lot of string identifiers and keys. I'm developing a game through unity c# and git, is it possible to specify something in the script so that unity loads a line from a file during build? (to make a file with these keys and add it to gitignore)

The Unity build process is very scriptable. Look at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IPreprocessBuildWithReport.OnPreprocessBuild.html and such. Of course, once you embed a secret into a build it isn't secret anymore.
